How to append collections with GeoNodes in Blender while reusing data and maintaining object control
I want to append a collection containing objects with geometry nodes modifiers applied to them. After appending, I still need to be able to manipulate the individual objects in the collection as usual.
The file I'm appending to already has data blocks (node groups, materials, etc.) with the same content and names. I want Blender to reuse this existing data instead of creating unnecessary copies.
I've tried two solutions so far:

Using the Asset Browser with "Append (Reuse Data)":

This method reuses the data as intended.
However, I can't "open up" the collection to manipulate individual objects.
When I use "Make Instances Real," it creates many duplicates of the original objects, causing a mess. This seems to be a known issue.
Using "Realize Instances" on a complex node tree creates other issues.


Using "File > Append":

This method does not reuse data; instead, it creates copies of all materials, geometry nodes, node groups, etc.
However, I can still manipulate the individual objects in the collection.



Attached are two example files. File A contains all the assets. File B already has two of the assets with the same data blocks. I want to append the collection named "Preset 1" from File A to File B.
Is there a way to append this collection, reuse the existing data blocks, and still be able to manipulate the individual objects without creating duplicates or other issues?



Hello, unfortunately this workflow is not ideal and the devs are working on improving it. See the discussion over on devtalk https://devtalk.blender.org/t/asset-embedding-proposal/34484

@Gorgious Hi, thanks for referencing that. It's good to know it's a known issue.
Would you think about any other workarounds? For example a script that would automatically find duplicate data blocks and merge them back to their base version?

The issue is there is no builtin way to know for sure if two assets are essentially the same. You could use a complicated hash map that would make sure every combination of every property of each data block produces a different value, so if you test two hash maps and they are equal you know for sure that they are the same asset, but what if you move a node in the node tree and the hash map suddenly changes ? The node tree produces the same output but is not strictly the same. BTW the devs go into much more detail than that. It's a complicated topic.

It is possible if you have a specific workflow for example to set a unique uuid as a custom property to your data blocks, and then with a custom addon deal with merging similar assets on append. But it is indeed a lot of work and very workflow-dependant

@Gorgious Thanks for clarifying that. It sounds pretty complicated and time-consuming indeed to do that. I guess we'll have to wait and see if they are able to come up with a solution. And support the Blender fund. :-)
